# Weird error in unsigned long*double multiplication

Tags: c++, debugging, type-conversion

I am completely confused by this error that keeps happening in my program, here's an excerpt of a `gdb` session with the relevant piece of code (blank lines and omissions mine):

```
(gdb) list
81    Candidate& rankSelect() {
82      float x = (std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(0, 1))(Context::rng);
83      /*debug*/ auto sz = pop.size();
84      /*debug*/ float a = -(float)sz*log(1 - x + x*exp(-1));
85      /*debug*/ float b = -sz*log(1 - x + x*exp(-1));
86      return pop[-(float)pop.size()*log(1 - x + x*exp(-1))];
87    }
88  
...

(gdb) frame
...
86      return pop[-(float)pop.size()*log(1 - x + x*exp(-1))];

(gdb) print sz
$1 = 500

(gdb) ptype sz
type = unsigned long

(gdb) print a
$2 = 54,559597

(gdb) print b
$3 = -2,0128938e+18
```

As can be seen, I had to add an explicit conversion of `pop.size()`, which is just a small integer (of type `size_type` aka `unsigned long` as `pop` is a `vector<>`), otherwise the result to be used as an index is an utter nonsense and caused a segment violation. All the other values are quite well-behaved, the logarithm is guaranteed to be between `0` and `-1`. Yet `-500` times it is suddenly several negative quintillions?!

More strangely, I haven't been able to isolate a MWE. Statements like `500*log(whatever)`, `(size_t)500*log(whatever)`, `(float)500*log(whatever)` all return the same, as expected.

Any ideas what's going on here?

**EDIT:** Following the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268085/1537925) it turns out that in line 85 `-sz` is performed before the multiplication, and because `sz` has not been coerced into a floating point number yet, this result in something near `ULONG_MAX`. Still I would say this is unexpected behaviour because mathematically multiplication should happen first...

Comment: "size_type aka unsigned long". Naughty. On windows x64 it ain't.

Comment: I don't depend on that. It would fit in any `int`.

Comment: Here ```float b = -sz*log(1 - x + x*exp(-1));``` i think the compiler tries to compute and store everything in an unsigned long, and it overflows.

Comment: Try this: ```unsigned long sz = 2;
    float x  = 0.5;
    auto z = log(1 - x + x*exp(-1));
    std::cout << z  << "\n";
    float a = -(float)sz*z;
    float b = -z*sz;```

For me the output is:

```0.759771 0.759771```

Comment: The problem was that at first the compiler did -x, which was an unsigned, and with - it overflowed. :)

Comment: @HansPassant: none, I can view the disassembly and roughly map it to the commands I call.

Comment: @RoxanaIstrate: Thanks, it was the latter indeed! (+1) I can't agree with the former as after the multiplication we're already in double (so it's not *everything* the compiler stores in an UL). I would have thought that happens before the unary minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

negation is performed before the multiplication.
Therefore, -sz performs negation on the **unsigned number** sz, which yields a very big number (unsigned numbers cannot become negative).

If you want to know how that works, have a look at the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) page on Wikipedia.

Since log(1 - x + x*exp(-1)) is a negative floating point number, the final result is a very big negative floating point number.

Comment: You're right! Putting braces around the expression before negating it like this `-(sz*log(1 - x + x*exp(-1)))` solved the problem – and it also explains perfectly what happened and why!

Comment: I must have expected `*` takes precedence over `-` like it does in math :-)

Comment: The same thing i explained in the comments 20 minutes ago. :-8

Comment: @RoxanaIstrate Sorry I found both about the same time (was looking at the disassembly in the meantime). But one can't accept a comment, can they?